# what is a pages_hashed in sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table...?

Tags: mysql, schema, mysql-workbench, innodb

Can someone explain me what is a `pages_hashed` in `sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table`...?

```
mysql> select * from sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table;
+---------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| object_schema | object_name               | allocated  | data      | pages | pages_hashed | pages_old | rows_cached |
+---------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| sbtest        | sbtest1                   | 107.25 MiB | 98.86 MiB |  6864 |            0 |      2597 |      721229 |
| InnoDB System | SYS_TABLES                | 3.36 MiB   | 3.03 MiB  |   215 |            0 |         0 |       18889 |
| mysql         | help_keyword              | 112.00 KiB | 73.24 KiB |     7 |            0 |         0 |         472 |
| mysql         | help_topic                | 96.00 KiB  | 53.27 KiB |     6 |            0 |         0 |         206 |
| mysql         | help_category             | 32.00 KiB  | 6.29 KiB  |     2 |            0 |         0 |          40 |
| mysql         | engine_cost               | 16.00 KiB  | 112 bytes |     1 |            0 |         0 |           2 |
| mysql         | gtid_executed             | 16.00 KiB  | 0 bytes   |     1 |            0 |         0 |           0 |
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

To understand what this table is showing, we have to understand 'sys' and what it's table are.

**What is the 'sys' schema??**

> The MySQL '**sys**' schema is a collection of views, functions, and
>   procedures that aggregate MySQL internal data into meaningful tables
>   that can be queried against.

The specific table (`sys`.`innodb_buffer_stats_by_table`) is a ***view***.

Here's the SQL that creates the "[Pages_hashed](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys/blob/master/views/i_s/innodb_buffer_stats_by_table.sql)" column:

```sql
COUNT(IF(ibp.is_hashed = 'YES', 1, NULL)) AS pages_hashed
```

the `ibp` mentioned in the above code is actually an abbreviation for `information_schema`.`INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE` table.

**What is the "pages_hashed" column?**

> The "pages_hashed" column shows how many pages are in the
>   `INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE` table that have the "IS_HASHED" column marked
>   "YES" for the specific table

*EXAMPLE*: If table "foo" has 100 pages and 25 of those pages are "hashed," then there will be 25 rows inside of `information_schema`.`INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE` with `TABLE_NAME='foo'` & `IS_HASHED='YES'`

**What is a hashed page?**

According to the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-buffer-page-table.html), a hashed page is determined by:

> Whether a hash index has been built on this page

To learn more about hash indexes, [check out the MySQL Dev Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)